# How to add Regular Expression with Pin Code or Zip Code?

Tags: java

I am using EditText with Input Type = number. But the issue I am facing is in number *,(),/,. all these symbols are also getting include. How to make regular expression for it and set it.

Below is mine code

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    if (editTextPinCode.getEditText().getText().length() == 6) {
        getPinFromAPI();
        editTextPinCode.setError(null);
        editTextStoreAddress.requestFocus();
    } else {
        editTextPinCode.setError("Enter Valid PinCode");
    }

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Comment: What platform? Is this Android? If so it would be good to add the "android" tag. Or likewise for Swing adding the "swing" tag, etc.

Comment: `if (editTextPinCode.getEditText().getText().matches("\\d{6}"))` should work

Comment: @AlexRudenko .matches giving error. I am doing in android

Comment: @DeekshaSharma, Oh, really? Documentation at [developer.android.com for `java.lang.String::matches`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String#matches(java.lang.String)) is unaware of it.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex to check if the text entered was exactly 6 digits.

```
if (editTextPinCode.getEditText().getText().matches("[0-9]{6}"))
```